# Removing 0 from Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, counters

I'm trying to create fancy chapter headers using KOMA-Script, and one thing that I've noticed is that the table of contents is always numbered 0 because I'm accessing the chapter counter. Is there a way to do this only for chapters 1 and up? i.e. if `\thechapter > 0` then access it, otherwise don't.

Here's a MWE that hopefully describes what I mean:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\KOMAoption{appendixprefix}{false}
\KOMAoption{chapterprefix}{false}
\KOMAoption{cleardoublepage}{empty}
\KOMAoption{DIV}{12}
\KOMAoption{draft}{false}
\KOMAoption{fontsize}{12pt}
\KOMAoption{headings}{big}
\KOMAoption{paper}{a4}
\KOMAoption{parskip}{half}
\KOMAoption{toc}{indent,bibliography}
\KOMAoption{twoside}{semi}
\KOMAoption{captions}{signature}
\KOMAoption{titlepage}{false}
\KOMAoption{abstract}{true}

% KOMA is complaining and apparently this fixes it =/
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{listings}

% Split document into multiple parts
\usepackage{subfiles}

% e-TeX tools
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Colours - put this before typography so additional named colours can be defined.
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{rmitred}{HTML}{CF102F}

%% Typography Settings
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\makeatletter
\setkomafont{chapter}{\let\@hangfrom\chapterhang\let\raggedsection\raggedright\fontsize{28}{28}\mdseries}
\makeatother
\newbox\chapternumberbox
\newbox\chapternamebox
\newcommand{\chapterhang}[2]{%
  \savebox\chapternumberbox{\fontsize{96}{96}\sffamily\color{rmitred}\arabic{chapter}}
  \raisebox{0em}{\usebox\chapternumberbox}
  \parbox[b][1\height][b]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd\chapternumberbox}{\raggedright #2}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\label{ch:introduction}

\section{A Section}

This is an introduction

\chapter{Improving Chapter Styling}

\section{Why}

Why do we want to do this thing? Because fancy.

\section{How}

How do we do this thing?

\chapter{The Second Chapter}

Some important things

\chapter{The Third Chapter}

Lorem ipsum etc

\chapter{Conclusion}

Lorem ipsum etc

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code does not compile

Comment: I forgot to remove the font loading code from the chapter definition. This was a stripped version of the document I'm working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the missing font feature, the code

```
\ifnum\value{chapter} > 0
  \savebox{...}% with \arabic{chapter}
\else
  \savebox{...}% Without \arabic{chapter}
\fi
```

works for me.

Conditionals about counter values can be done with `\ifnum\value{countername} .... \if`

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\KOMAoption{appendixprefix}{false}
\KOMAoption{chapterprefix}{false}
\KOMAoption{cleardoublepage}{empty}
\KOMAoption{DIV}{12}
\KOMAoption{draft}{false}
\KOMAoption{fontsize}{12pt}
\KOMAoption{headings}{big}
\KOMAoption{paper}{a4}
\KOMAoption{parskip}{half}
\KOMAoption{toc}{indent,bibliography}
\KOMAoption{twoside}{semi}
\KOMAoption{captions}{signature}
\KOMAoption{titlepage}{false}
\KOMAoption{abstract}{true}

% KOMA is complaining and apparently this fixes it =/
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{listings}

% Split document into multiple parts
\usepackage{subfiles}

% e-TeX tools
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Colours - put this before typography so additional named colours can be defined.
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{rmitred}{HTML}{CF102F}

%% Typography Settings
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\makeatletter
\setkomafont{chapter}{\let\@hangfrom\chapterhang\let\raggedsection\raggedright\fontsize{28}{28}\mdseries}
\makeatother
\newbox\chapternumberbox
\newbox\chapternamebox

\newcommand{\chapterhang}[2]{%
%  \savebox\chapternumberbox{\fontsize{96}{96}\rmitfont\color{rmitred}\arabic{chapter}} 
  \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 
  \savebox\chapternumberbox{\fontsize{96}{96}\color{rmitred}\arabic{chapter}}%
  \raisebox{0em}{\usebox\chapternumberbox} 
  \else
  \savebox\chapternumberbox{\fontsize{96}{96}\color{rmitred}}
  \raisebox{0em}{\usebox\chapternumberbox}% 
  \fi
  \parbox[b][1\height][b]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd\chapternumberbox}{\raggedright #2}%
}



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\label{ch:introduction}

\section{A Section}

This is an introduction

\chapter{Improving Chapter Styling}

\section{Why}

Why do we want to do this thing? Because fancy.

\section{How}

How do we do this thing?

\chapter{The Second Chapter}

Some important things

\chapter{The Third Chapter}

Lorem ipsum etc

\chapter{Conclusion}

Lorem ipsum etc

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @zoqaeski: Well, you spoke of `ToC` only, not of Appendix numbering -- that's another question actually! And your example does have appendices at all!

Answer (score 1):

Note that `\addtokomafont` and `\setkomafont` should only be used to switch font attributes.

Here is a suggestion redefining `\chapterformat` and `\chapterlinesformat` (needs KOMA-Script version 3.19a or newer) that also works for unnumbered chapters inside the document.

```
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{28}{28}\selectfont\mdseries}
\renewcommand\chapterformat{%
  {\fontsize{96}{96}\selectfont\textcolor{rmitred}{\thechapter}}\ }

\newbox\chapternumberbox
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#2}{}{
      \parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\raggedright#3}%
    }{%
      \savebox\chapternumberbox{#2}%
      \usebox\chapternumberbox%
      \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\wd\chapternumberbox\relax}{\raggedright#3}%
  }\par\nobreak
}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}[2015/10/03]
\KOMAoption{appendixprefix}{false}
\KOMAoption{chapterprefix}{false}
\KOMAoption{cleardoublepage}{empty}
\KOMAoption{DIV}{12}
\KOMAoption{draft}{false}
\KOMAoption{fontsize}{12pt}
\KOMAoption{headings}{big}
\KOMAoption{paper}{a4}
\KOMAoption{parskip}{half}
\KOMAoption{toc}{indent,bibliography}
\KOMAoption{twoside}{semi}
\KOMAoption{captions}{signature}
\KOMAoption{titlepage}{false}
\KOMAoption{abstract}{true}

% KOMA is complaining and apparently this fixes it =/
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{listings}

% Split document into multiple parts
\usepackage{subfiles}

% e-TeX tools
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Colours - put this before typography so additional named colours can be defined.
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{rmitred}{HTML}{CF102F}

%% Typography Settings
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{28}{28}\selectfont\mdseries}
\renewcommand\chapterformat{%
  {\fontsize{96}{96}\selectfont\textcolor{rmitred}{\thechapter}}\ }

\newbox\chapternumberbox
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#2}{}{
      \parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\raggedright#3}%
    }{%
      \savebox\chapternumberbox{#2}%
      \usebox\chapternumberbox%
      \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\wd\chapternumberbox\relax}{\raggedright#3}%
  }\par\nobreak
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{ch:introduction}
\section{A Section}
This is an introduction
\chapter{Improving Chapter Styling}
\section{Why}
Why do we want to do this thing? Because fancy.
\section{How}
How do we do this thing?
\chapter{The Second Chapter}
Some important things
\chapter{The Third Chapter}
Lorem ipsum etc
\chapter{Conclusion}
Lorem ipsum etc
\addchap{An unnumbered chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I kept reading the KOMA documentation and found advice along those lines. I also achieved the same result by using a whole lot of boxes in the `\chapterformat` command, which let me play with moving various bits around, but I assume that approach is the more naïve one?

Comment: With `scrreprt` or `scrbook` redefining `\chapterformat` is the suggested way to format the chapter number. Since version 3.19 it is possible to change the order and/or the layout of the already formated chapter number and chapter title by redefining `\chapterlinesformat` or `\chapterlineswithprefixformat`. In your example the redefinition of `\chapterlinesformat` is only needed to ensure that the chapter number is bottom aligned with the last line of a longer chapter heading. You could remove it if all chapter headings are one-line.

Comment: Oh, ok. Some of the ideas I was toying with included putting the chapter number above the chapter title, and possibly inserting a graphic in as well. I've seen some rather nice reports made with InDesign and I figured I could probably get the same results with LaTeX with some effort.